# How can I avoid this for loop in pytorch? Is there a function for efficient computation?

Tags: performance, pytorch

I have the following code in my Pytorch neural net:

```
cos = nn.CosineSimilarity(dim=1)

d = torch.zeros(batch_sz, n, n).to(device="cuda")
    
for i in range(n):
   for j in range(n):
       d[:, i, j] = cos(q[:, i, :], k[:, j, :])
```

`q` and `k` are both of size `(batch_sz, n, m)`.
This piece of Code obviously slows down my program and I'm wondering if Pytorch offers any functions that might make this more efficient.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to vectorize using `nn.CosineSimilarity` but you could use this vectorized implementation. It computes the cosine similarity in the same way as PyTorch's internal module.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import time

# some dummy inputs
n=20
m=30
batch_sz = 10

k = torch.rand(batch_sz, n, m)
q = torch.rand(batch_sz, n, m)
d = torch.zeros(batch_sz, n, n)


cos = nn.CosineSimilarity(dim=1)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        d[:, i, j] = cos(q[:, i, :], k[:, j, :])



# dot product (numerator)
out = torch.bmm(q, k.transpose(1,2))

# computing the denominator in the next 5 steps

# compute the norm and restore dimensions
q_norm = q.norm(dim=2).unsqueeze(2)
k_norm = k.norm(dim=2).unsqueeze(1)

# This repeats the norms along dim 2 for q and dim 1 for k
q_norm_expanded = q_norm.expand(batch_sz, n, n)
k_norm_expanded = k_norm.expand(batch_sz, n, n)

# we compute the product. 
norms = q_norm_expanded* k_norm_expanded

# cosine similarity
out = out/(norms+1e-9)

print(torch.allclose(d, out))
```

The process of expanding and multiplying the norms is actually computing the outer product. So you could use also use this operation:

```
norms = torch.bmm(q_norm, k_norm)
```

instead of

```
q_norm_expanded = q_norm.expand(batch_sz, n, n)
k_norm_expanded = k_norm.expand(batch_sz, n, n)

norms = q_norm_expanded* k_norm_expanded
```

I just realized you could normalize the vectors before hand for a **More concise and computationally stable version**

```
q_norm = q.norm(dim=2)+1e-9
k_norm = k.norm(dim=2)+1e-9
q = q/q_norm.unsqueeze(2)
k = k/k_norm.unsqueeze(2)

out = torch.bmm(q, k.transpose(1,2))
```